# What are the best ways to increase my Cyberware Capacity?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Currently, I am level 60 with all of the relevant perks from the Technical Tree, but I would like to have more Cyberware capacity. As far as I understand, at the point I am at the only way to increase my Cyberware is to get more of the Cyberware Progression Shards.

Are there any other ways to increase my Cyberware capacity? And if not, are there any good/efficient ways to grind more Cyberware Progression Shards aside from just finding them randomly?

Answer (score 2):

You could try and get yourself a cyberware capacity booster called a "Chrome compressor" BUT it takes away your OS slot so you can't use something like a sandevistan or berserk. You can usually get it in Dogtown but I think it appears at base game rippers later in the game

Comment: Oh, neat. I don't think I have stumbled across that one- it does provide a lot of capacity.  Though it taking up the OS Slot is quite a price to pay- I love my Sandevistan too much :(